# Fitting Voigt function to data in Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I recently got a script running to fit a gaussian to my absorption profile with [help of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047395/fitting-gaussian-to-absorbtion-line-in-python). My hope was that things would work fine if I simply replace the Gauss function by a Voigt one, but this seems not to be the case. I think mainly due to the fact that it is a shifted voigt.

Edit: The profiles are absorption lines that vary in optical thickness. In practice they will be a mix between optically thick and thin features. Like the bottom part in this diagram. The current data will be more like the top image, but maybe the bottom is already flattened a bit. (And we only see the left side of the profile, a bit beyond the center)
[image]

For a Gauss it looks like this and as predicted the bottom seems to be less deep than the fit wants it to be, but still quite close. The profile itself should still be a voigt though. But now I realize that the central points might throw off the fit. So maybe a weight should be added based on wing position? 
[image]

I'm mostly wondering if the shifted function could be mis-defined or if its my starting values.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import wofz

x = np.arange(13)
xx = xx = np.linspace(0, 13, 100)
y = np.array([19699.959 , 21679.445 , 21143.195 , 20602.875 , 16246.769 ,
        11635.25  ,  8602.465 ,  7035.493 ,  6697.0337,  6510.092 ,
              7717.772 , 12270.446 , 16807.81  ])
# weighted arithmetic mean (corrected - check the section below)
#mean = 2.4
sigma = 2.4
gamma = 2.4

def Gauss(x, y0, a, x0, sigma):
    return y0 + a * np.exp(-(x - x0)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))


def Voigt(x, x0, y0, a, sigma, gamma):
    #sigma = alpha / np.sqrt(2 * np.log(2))

    return y0 + a * np.real(wofz((x - x0 + 1j*gamma)/sigma/np.sqrt(2))) / sigma /np.sqrt(2*np.pi)


popt, pcov = curve_fit(Voigt, x, y, p0=[8, np.max(y), -(np.max(y)-np.min(y)), sigma, gamma])
#p0=[8, np.max(y), -(np.max(y)-np.min(y)), mean, sigma])

plt.plot(x, y, 'b+:', label='data')
plt.plot(xx, Voigt(xx, *popt), 'r-', label='fit')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you add the values for x and y, please? Also, xx.

Comment: Oh sorry! Done now

Comment: Actually, lineshapes should be Lorentzian and they get broadened into a Gaussian. So, now what you're doing it not broadening your gauss but actually making it tighter.

Comment: There are imports missing in the code, please provide a full working example!

Comment: Added some more information about the problem and the imports.

Comment: If you are able to make multiple data collection runs, I suggest taking several data sets and plotting them together on the same scatterplot, My suspicion is that you have a large measurement noise component affecting the fit, and this is partly because the data to the extreme left of the plot appears to curve downward. Multiple data collection runs plotted together should show the size and effect of any measurement noise.

Answer (score 2):

I may be misunderstanding the model you're using, but I think you would need to include some sort of constant or linear background.

To do that with `lmfit` (which has Voigt, Gaussian, and many other models built in, and tries very hard to make these interchangeable), I would suggest starting with something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel, VoigtModel, LinearModel, ConstantModel

x = np.arange(13)
xx = np.linspace(0, 13, 100)
y = np.array([19699.959 , 21679.445 , 21143.195 , 20602.875 , 16246.769 ,
              11635.25  ,  8602.465 ,  7035.493 ,  6697.0337,  6510.092 ,
              7717.772 , 12270.446 , 16807.81  ])

# build model as Voigt + Constant
## model = GaussianModel() + ConstantModel()
model = VoigtModel() + ConstantModel()

# create parameters with initial values
params = model.make_params(amplitude=-1e5, center=8, 
                           sigma=2, gamma=2, c=25000)

# maybe place bounds on some parameters
params['center'].min = 2
params['center'].max = 12
params['amplitude'].max = 0. 

# do the fit, print out report with results 
result = model.fit(y, params, x=x)
print(result.fit_report())

# plot data, best fit, fit interpolated to `xx`
plt.plot(x, y, 'b+:', label='data')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, 'ko', label='fitted points')
plt.plot(xx, result.eval(x=xx), 'r-', label='interpolated fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And, yes, you can simply replace `VoigtModel()` with `GaussianModel()` or `LorentzianModel()` and redo the fit and compare the fit statistics to see which model is better.

For the Voigt model fit, the printed report would be

```
[[Model]]
    (Model(voigt) + Model(constant))
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 41
    # data points      = 13
    # variables        = 4
    chi-square         = 17548672.8
    reduced chi-square = 1949852.54
    Akaike info crit   = 191.502014
    Bayesian info crit = 193.761811
[[Variables]]
    amplitude: -173004.338 +/- 30031.4068 (17.36%) (init = -100000)
    center:     8.06574198 +/- 0.16209266 (2.01%) (init = 8)
    sigma:      1.96247322 +/- 0.23522096 (11.99%) (init = 2)
    c:          23800.6655 +/- 1474.58991 (6.20%) (init = 25000)
    gamma:      1.96247322 +/- 0.23522096 (11.99%) == 'sigma'
    fwhm:       7.06743644 +/- 0.51511574 (7.29%) == '1.0692*gamma+sqrt(0.8664*gamma**2+5.545083*sigma**2)'
    height:    -18399.0337 +/- 2273.61672 (12.36%) == '(amplitude/(max(2.220446049250313e-16, sigma*sqrt(2*pi))))*wofz((1j*gamma)/(max(2.220446049250313e-16, sigma*sqrt(2)))).real'
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(amplitude, c)     = -0.957
    C(amplitude, sigma) = -0.916
    C(sigma, c)         =  0.831
    C(center, c)        = -0.151
```

Note that by default `gamma` is constrained to be the same value as `sigma`.   This constraint can be lifted and `gamma` made to vary independently with  `params['gamma'].set(expr=None, vary=True, min=1.e-9)`.  I think that you may not have enough data points in this data set to robustly and independently determine `gamma`.

The plot for that fit would look like this:
[image]

Comment: This looks nice! The last 3-4 points are the background, the rest is the line. (Its very sub optimal, but its the only data set that we have of this unfortunately. Is it possible to tell it to use the first 3-4 points as the continuum and tell it not to move above that? I also played with weights, as the central points are optically thick and not model-able with a voigt. I'm personally mostly interested in the shift and the width of the profile, so that gamma in this case I think.

Comment: As I said above, I may not understand you. The **last** 3-4 points are in the background?  You mean the peak is centered at around 1 or 2 and has a positive amplitude? Or are the **first** 3-4 peaks the background, with the peak being centered around 8 and having a negative amplitude?   For sure, that shows that you have some work to do in understanding the signals you are modeling.  The mechanics of doing the fit are relatively simple compared to understanding the model.   Also: for a Voigt profile, `gamma` gives the width of the Lorentzian-like tail. "shift of the width" is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get something, but not very satisfying. If you remove the offset as a parameter and add `20000` directly in the `Voigt` function, with starting values `[8, 126000, 0.71, 2]` (the particular values don't' matter much) you'll get something like

[image]

Now, the fit produces a value for `gamma` which is negative which I cannot really justify. I would expect `gamma` to always be positive, but maybe I'm wrong and it's completely fine.

One thing you could try is to mirror your data so that its a "positive" peak (and while at it removing the background) and/or normalize the values. That might help you in the convergence.

I have no idea why when using the offset as a parameter the solver has problems finding an optimum. Maybe you need a different optimizer routine.

Maybe it'll be a better option to use the `lmfit` package that it's a wrapper over scipy to fit nonlinear functions with many prebuilt lineshapes. There is even an [example](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#example-1-fit-peak-data-to-gaussian-lorentzian-and-voigt-profiles) of fitting a `Voigt` profile.